# Inverter efeito de transição CSS3

Tags: css3

Gostaria de saber como posso inverter o efeito de transição de elementos com CSS3

```js
$('span').on('click', function(){

  if($(this).text() == 'Mostrar Efeito')
  {
      $('div').css('max-height', '250px');
      $(this).text('Resetar');
  }
  else
  {
       $('div').css('max-height', '0');
       $(this).text('Mostrar Efeito');
  }

});
```

```css
div{

  background-color: coral;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

span{

  cursor: pointer;
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Mostrar Efeito</span>
<div></div>
```

Percebe-se que neste pequeno exemplo que criei o efeito começa de cima e vai para baixo. Gostaria de saber como consigo inverter este efeito de baixo para cima. Tentei achar na internet algo parecido mas sem sucesso (acho que pela falta de conseguir formatar a dúvida corretamente).

Comment: Na verdade ele não está indo de cima para baixo, ele apenas está aumentando e assim procurando espaço para deslocar e "caber", ou seja todos elementos sempre irão aumentar porque começam de cima em HTML. Eu poderia sugerir `position: relative`+`position: absolute` que irá funcionar, mas não sei exatamente o que você quer.

Comment: Ok, então ele aumenta de cima vindo pra baixo... Quero que ele aumente de baixo vindo pra cima.. Como diz na pergunta

Comment: Você entendeu o que eu disse? De cima pra baixo é apenas uma sensação, ele não está vindo de cima na real, ele esta apenas deslocando espaço. Vou postar uma sugestão de qualquer forma.

Comment: Entendi o que você disse, e você também entendeu o que eu disse.. então é só nos adaptarmos aos nossos entendimentos, que chegamos numa resposta como fez o Gabriel, eu posso ter me expressado de uma forma errada mas no fim das contas vc sabia qual era a dúvida..

Comment: Não é questão de um entendeu o outro, a questão era apenas entender que isso é apenas uma percepção, a parte que disse, *não sei o que exatamente você quer*, se refere se o `position` funcionaria ou não pra você porque não sei aonde de sua página você usaria, pois adicionar algo assim poderia quebrar a página toda. Entende? Mas que bom que deu certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem saber a sua intenção, fica um pouco complicado de conseguir uma solução exata, mas é como o Guilherme disse nos comentários que por padrão ele cresce e o espaço para crescer é para baixo.

Você pode fazer uma div com o tamanho que deseja e coloca `position: relative` depois pode criar o box que irá usar em uma div com `position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0%;` e depois quando fizer o efeito irá fazer um `height: 100%`

```js
$('span').on('click', function(){

  if($(this).text() == 'Mostrar Efeito')
  {
      $('div#box').animate({'height': '100%'}, 200);
      $(this).text('Resetar');
  }
  else
  {
       $('div#box').animate({'height': '0%'}, 200);
       $(this).text('Mostrar Efeito');
  }

});
```

```css
div#content{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
div#box{

  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

span{

  cursor: pointer;
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Mostrar Efeito</span>
<div id="content">
  <div id="box">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quando for assim, você pode criar um exemplo funcional por aqui mesmo, ou pelo `JSFiddle`

Comment: Nesse caso ai eu usei o animate, que deixa um pouco mais simples no jquery, mas pode usar como estava usando também!

Comment: eu ia postar um exemplo, mas o seu está otimo +1

Comment: Só não consigo entender porque vocês precisam saber a intenção da coisa.. (a dúvida era só essa mesmo) Muito obrigado pela resposta, agora com ela posso modifica-la aprimora-la se possível e conseguir aplicar em qualquer situação.